# How to do custom validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, input, dom-events

I have a function that currently works with an input to prevent customers from inputting a *P.O. Box* into an address field. The input that works has an inline `onKeyPress` event, however the input I need to run the function on doesn't (and I can't access it).

My question is how to incorporate the correct event listener so that my function runs on this inaccessible input?

My JS Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQS9/4/

```js
function killPObox(id) {
  var idValue = document.getElementById('v65-onepage-shipaddr1').value; 
  if (id == 'v65-onepage-shipaddr1') {
    function runVal() {
      if (idValue.substr(0,4).toUpperCase() === "PO B" || idValue.substr(0,5) === "P.O. ") {
        alert("USA Light cannot ship to P.O. Boxes. Please enter a street address.");
      }
    }
    setInterval(runVal(),1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Practice input that works -->
1. <input type="text" class="quantity" name="v65-onepage-shipaddr1" id="v65-onepage-shipaddr1" onKeyPress="killPObox(this.name)">  
<br>
<br>
<!-- Actual input that I need to hook into, cannot edit -->
2. <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="75" name="ShipAddress1" id="v65-onepage-shipaddr1" value="" style="" onkeydown="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `addEventListener()` method like this:

```
document.getElementById('v65-onepage-shipaddr2').addEventListener('keypress', killPObox('v65-onepage-shipaddr2'));
```

I think your first input is incorrectly passing `this.name` as the argument to the `killPObox()` function. Should you be passing `this.id` instead? Also you may want to replace `'v65-onepage-shipaddr1'` in your `killPObox()` function to just `id` to use the argument passed into the function.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added this to the script, but it still doesn't act on the second input.  Do you have a JSFiddle where it's working?

Comment: change the `id`'s value of the second `input` to `"v65-onepage-shipaddr2"`. You shouldn't be using two same `id`'s. You should figure out what `id`'s to use. I am just making a suggestion to help debug the issue you are having.

Comment: I changed it the IDs to match, and I'm still able to type 'PO Box' into the field without getting an alert.  You can see here it's still not working, but I'm probably not integrating the event listener correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQS9/5/

Answer (score 1):

*I'm sure you have solved this already, but since this is still unanswered (and I stumbled on it) I'll add the solution for future visitors.*

**Use the correct event**
First off, the `onKeyPress` will actually fire before the typed character has been registered in the input element. So if a user types `abc` and you do `onKeyPress="alert(this.value)"` it would alert `ab`. A better alternative would  be `onKeyUp`, since this would get the last typed character too.

**Use the event correctly**
Next, the `events` - your options are:

```js
//inline, not considered "best practice"
<input type="text" name="myinput" id="myinput" onKeyUp="killPObox(this)"/>

//same event as above, but in pure js
document.getElementById('myinput').onkeyup = function (e) {
    killPObox(e.target);
};

//or attach an eventListener
document.getElementById('myinput').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    killPObox(e.target)
});
```

All of these should work for the majority of browsers. I would suggest alternative 3, or if you need IE8 support, alternative 2.

**The JavaScript, simplified**
Your function, `killPObox()`, should look something like this (using one of the above events):

```
function killPObox(el) {
    if (el.id == 'v65-onepage-shipaddr1' || el.id == 'v65-onepage-shipaddr2') {
        if (el.value.substr(0, 4).toUpperCase() === "PO B" || el.value.substr(0, 5) === "P.O. ") {
            alert("USA Light cannot ship to P.O. Boxes. Please enter a street address.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Last but not least..**
Finally, a very important part when using event binding, you need to use `window.onload()`. This is to make sure that both the script and elements that are to be bound are loaded before any code is run.

```
window.onload = function () {
    // my binds, events and calls here
};
```

An actual working example of all three events:

```js
function killPObox(el) {
    if (el.id == 'v65-onepage-shipaddr0' || el.id == 'v65-onepage-shipaddr1' || el.id == 'v65-onepage-shipaddr2') {
        if (el.value.substr(0, 4).toUpperCase() === "PO B" || el.value.substr(0, 5) === "P.O. ") {
            alert("USA Light cannot ship to P.O. Boxes. Please enter a street address.");
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('v65-onepage-shipaddr1').onkeyup = function (e) {
        killPObox(e.target);
    };
    document.getElementById('v65-onepage-shipaddr2').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        killPObox(e.target)
    });
};
```

```html
"PO B" or "P.O. " will trigger the alert in all boxes:<br><br>
0. <input type="text" class="quantity" name="v65-onepage-shipaddr0" id="v65-onepage-shipaddr0" onKeyUp="killPObox(this)" /> 
<br/><br/>
1. <input type="text" class="quantity" name="v65-onepage-shipaddr1" id="v65-onepage-shipaddr1" />
<br/><br/>
2. <input type="text" class="quantity" name="v65-onepage-shipaddr2" id="v65-onepage-shipaddr2" />
```